# irregular slicing in numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, slice

consider the below `numpy array`

```
a = np.arange(20)
```

and the slicing requirement give below

```
b = [[0,4],
     [4,9],
     [9,15],
     [15,19]]
```

how can i slice `'a'` based on irregular slicing information in `'b'`? like for example:

```
np.mean(a[b[:,0]:b[:,1]])
```

I know how to achieve this with loop statement, like

```
[np.mean(a[b[_][0]:b[_][1]]) for _ in range(len(b))]
```

but is there a way in which i can avoid using loops?

Comment: Would the start and stop always be coinciding?

Comment: Asking the same question as Divakar. If it is the case, you can just use `np.split`: `np.split(a, b[:, 1])`

Comment: yes. the start will always repeat the stop of the previous row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `np.split`.

```
>>> list(map(np.mean, np.split(a, b[:, 1])))
[1.5, 6.0, 11.5, 16.5, 19.0]
```

---

Using a *list comprehension*:

```
>>> [np.mean(x) for x in np.split(a, b[:, 1])]
[1.5, 6.0, 11.5, 16.5, 19.0]
```

Comment: @hpaulj Apologies, was drawing a blank when figuring out how to get the mean, and `map` was all I could think of. (I am aware of the speed constraints on this solution).

Comment: @SirajS. No problem! I'm not sure about the performance aspect. If you find it being too slow for your use case, please feel free to retract and use Psidom's answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.add.reduceat` with flattened `b` as the indices:

```
np.add.reduceat(a, np.ravel(b))[::2]/np.diff(b, axis=1).ravel()
# array([  1.5,   6. ,  11.5,  16.5])
```

with *for loop*:

```
[np.mean(a[b[_][0]:b[_][1]]) for _ in range(len(b))]
# [1.5, 6.0, 11.5, 16.5]
```

For more, you can see the first example in `help(np.add.reduceat)`:

> ```
> Examples
> --------
> To take the running sum of four successive values:
>
> >>> np.add.reduceat(np.arange(8),[0,4, 1,5, 2,6, 3,7])[::2]
> array([ 6, 10, 14, 18])
> ```

Comment: Definitely learned about `ufunc.reduce` and `ufunc.reduceat`  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Using `cumsum` and `np.diff`

```
c = b[:, 1]

np.diff(np.append(0, a.cumsum()[c - 1])) / np.diff(np.append(0, c))

array([  1.5,   6. ,  11.5,  16.5])
```